# Do I need to connect both GND and both VCC on this addressible LED?

Tags: led, pcb-design

I'm working with APA102-2020 addressable RGB LEDs (datasheet [here](http://www.led-color.com/upload/201604/APA102-2020%20SMD%20LED.pdf)). Each component has two GND pads and two VCC pads. Testing with a multimeter, I find that each pair of pads is connected (ie GND-GND and VCC-VCC). In the PCB I'm designing, should I connect both GND and both VCC pads, or do I only need to connect one of each? Why/why not?

The datasheet doesn't show these pads, but the datasheet is [known to be inaccurate in other ways](https://cpldcpu.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/understanding-the-apa102-superled/) so I'm not sure if I should fully trust it.

[image: APA102-2020 datasheet]

I only know what they are from the KiCAD footprint.

[image: APA102-2020 KiCAD footprint]

The LEDs look like this:

[image: APA102-2020]

Comment: There are both 6 pin and 8 pin versions of the apa102-2020 available.

Comment: They are probably more important thermally than electrically. If you are CERTAIN that ghnd pads are connected and Vcc pads are connected then thermal issues are probably the main consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should connect them.

A good datasheet would tell you that, but hey...

More connection points means better electrical contact (lower impedance overall), better mechanical strength and thermal management, there really is no advantage in not connecting them.